# Remove similar entries from TXT file?

Tags: php

I got two text files: **localhost.txt** and **host.txt**.

**localhost.txt** contains:

```
127.0.0.1:100
127.0.0.1:200
127.0.0.1:300
127.0.0.1:400
127.0.0.1:500
127.0.0.1:600
127.0.0.1:700
127.0.0.1:800
127.0.0.1:(...)
```

**host.txt** contains:

```
172.39.32.1:100
172.39.32.1:200
172.39.32.1:300
172.39.32.1:400
172.39.32.1:500
172.39.32.1:600
172.39.32.1:700
172.39.32.1:800
127.0.0.1:1300
127.0.0.1:1800
172.39.32.1:(...)
```

(...)
I'm using this script

```
$data = file("localhost.txt");
file_put_contents('host.txt', implode(array_unique($data))); 
$fisier = file_get_contents('host.txt');
```

to remove duplicates.

I need a script that will also remove similar lines e.g. if 127.0.0.1:200 in localhost.txt already exists in host.txt, then script will remove all lines with 127.0.0.1 from host.txt.

Any ideas? :)
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking -- you want to remove all entries for that hostname regardless of port?

Comment: Your second line will overwrite `host.txt` before it's been read. Is this intentional?

Comment: @leftclickben If line 127.0.0.1.200 from localhost.txt already exists in host.txt, then I need to remove from host.txt all lines matching IP in this case 127:0.0.1 :)

Comment: Does it have to be in PhP? And if then what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hosts_lines = file("hosts.txt");

foreach($hosts_lines as $line) {
    $temp = explode(":", $line);
    $hosts[$temp[0]][] = $temp[1];
}


$localhost = file("localhost.txt");

foreach ($localhost as $line) {
    $temp = explode(":", $line);
    unset($hosts[$temp[0]]);
}


foreach($hosts as $ip => $ports) {
    foreach ($ports as $port) {
        printf("%s:%s", $ip, $port);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have purchased ready-made script :)